# MySQL slow query becomes slower over time until completely timing out

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

**Database server:**

- Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server version: 10.4.27-MariaDB

**Web server:**

- Apache/2.4.54 (Win64)
- PHP version: 8.1.12
- phpMyAdmin version: 5.2.0

CPU usage at 10-15% and Memory usage at 30-40%

I am hoping to receive some guidance on how to improve or optimize a specific query. In parallel to the select queries I have a dozen load data queries that run every 10 and 30 seconds for real time display board. All the other select queries seem to run fine and stay under 2 seconds except for this one query which is okay for a while then I start to see it delay over time then eventually timeout completely.

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   `sfdc_chat_csat` 
   LEFT JOIN
      `sfdc_chat_review` 
      ON `sfdc_chat_csat`.`ChatKey__c` = `sfdc_chat_review`.`ChatKey` 
WHERE
   `sfdc_chat_csat`.`ChatRating__c` != '' 
   AND `sfdc_chat_csat`.`ChatRating__c` <= 6 
   AND `sfdc_chat_review`.`manager_review` IS NULL 
   AND 
   (
      `sfdc_chat_csat`.`Id` IN 
      (
         'a0b4z00000W48UyAAJ',
         'a0b4z00000W48V8AAJ',
         'a0b4z00000W4CGvAAN',
         'a0b4z00000W4CMAAA3',
         'a0b4z00000W4CRjAAN',
         'a0b4z00000W4CUTAA3',
         'a0b4z00000W4CW5AAN',
         'a0b4z00000W4DAoAAN',
         'a0b4z00000W4CEpAAN',
         'a0b4z00000W4CTaAAN'
      )
   )
   AND MONTH(`CreatedDate`) >= MONTH(now());
```

Here are the results from EXPLAIN query

```
+-----+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------+
| id  | select_type | table             | type     | possible_keys         | key     |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------+
| 1   | SIMPLE      | sfdc_chat_csat    | range    | PRIMARY,ChatRating__c | PRIMARY |
| 1   | SIMPLE      | sfdc_chat_review  | eq_ref   | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY |
+-----+-------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------------+---------+

continued

+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
| key_len | ref                                  | rows | Extra                   |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
| 122     | NULL                                 | 10   | Using where             |
| 122     | dashboard.sfdc_chat_csat.ChatKey__c  | 1    | Using where; Not exists |
+---------+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------------+
```

Here is the table structure for table `sfdc_chat_csat` (10k rows of data)

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id                        | varchar(40)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| IsDeleted                 | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ChatKey__c                | varchar(40)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| ChatRating__c             | varchar(40)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Chat_ButtonId             | varchar(40)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Chat_Button__c            | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Chat_Transcript_Number__c | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Chat_Transcript_Owner__c  | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Comments_del__c           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CreatedDate               | datetime     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Customer_Email_Address__c | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Customer_First_Name__c    | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Customer_Last_Name__c     | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| NPS_Score__c              | varchar(40)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here is the table structure for `sfdc_chat_review` (100 rows of data)

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ChatKey           | varchar(40)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| chatTranscriptId  | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| manager           | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| manager_review    | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| manager_verdict   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| false_reason_code | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| manager_comments  | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

When I run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; i see multiple instances of this query in a "Sending data" state. It seems when the Time reaches 20 (20 seconds?) then they drop off the Process list.

Not sure how i should proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good chance this is causing performance problems:

```
MONTH(`CreatedDate`) >= MONTH(now())
```

because `MONTH()` will be executed for every row and an index on `CreatedDate` will not be used.

Instead, put a condition on the raw value of `CreatedDate` that is logically equivalent:

```
CreatedDate >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(now())-1 DAY)
```

Create an index on `CreatedDate`.

You may find that using `BETWEEN` gives better performance than `>=`:

```
CreatedDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(now())-1 DAY) AND now()
```

because although it's logically the same (there will not be data for future times), the optimiser will see it as a *closed* range rather than an open-ended range.

Comment: I will try your suggestion.

In other places I have `CreatedDate >= CURDATE()`  do you have any recommendation to improve this also?

Comment: would this be ideal? `CreatedDate BETWEEN DATE(now()) AND now()`

Comment: You don't need condition like CurrentDate < now(). Just do CurrentDate >= SomeValue. It'll be less than now() automatically.